# MVVM wpf: How can I my connect my previously made ObservableCollection come across ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In the application I'm building. I seem to be having the problem that my previous inserted ObservableCollection for Categories, doesn't seem to be transferred from ViewModel to Viewmodel.

I've tried putting a public Category CategoryToEdit { get; set; } reference to bind it towards my type as CategoryToEdit.Type
Previously this worked for me to connect the selected data from another viewmodel. But this happened on a template without mvvm, and I can't seem to find the working solution to on it.

This is my MainWindowViewModel:

namespace Webadmin.ViewModels
{

```
  public class MainWindowViewModel

  {

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand ChangeCategoryClick { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

        ChangeCategoryClick = new RelayCommand(f => ChangeCategory(), null);

        Categories.Add(new Category() { Type = "Electronics" });
        Categories.Add(new Category() { Type = "Clothes" });
        Categories.Add(new Category() { Type = "Books" });

    }

    private void ChangeCategory()
    {        
        FilterWindow changeWindow = new FilterWindow
        {

        };          
        changeWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

}

This ChangeCategory is simply bound to a command on a button so it can change window.
Button Content="Change" Command="{Binding ChangeCategoryClick}"

This is my FilterWindowViewModel (where the previous filled in types should be displayed):

namespace Webadmin.ViewModels

{

```
   class FilterWindowViewModel

   {        

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public ICollectionView CategoryView { get; set; }

    public FilterWindowViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

        CategoryView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Categories);
        CategoryView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Type", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
}
```

}

I try to display my categories in FilterWindow Datagrid by using
DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"

But all I end up with is an empty table

The empty table should of course be created due to it being newly recreated in the FilterWindowViewModel. But what I want to have is let it be connected to main filled in categories. With that connection, I can add, delete, edit those categories so that my products bound those current categories could have the possibilty to have more/less/different to choose from.

Comment: You just create an empty ObservableCollection<Category> in your FilterWindowViewModel. So, of course you end up with an empty table. I don't really know what you are trying to achieve, but it seems to me you could just inject the Categories collection instance from the MainWindowViewModel into the FilterWindowViewModel, no?

Comment: You could pass a reference to the collection round using resources like the sample here does with people and colours. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Dynamic-XAML-Composed-View-e087f3c1  Each of the viewmodels for those 4 usercontrols gets a reference to a collection out of resources.

Answer (score 1):

This is where an MVVM framework can assist. For example, in [MVVM Light](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight), there is the concept of the Messenger that facilitates the communication between View Models for this exact scenario. The premise is that you fire off a message to indicate that your collection has changed. Those interested ViewModels would then register to receive that message.

```
public CategoryAddedMessage
{
    public Category AddedCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your `MainWindowViewModel`, you would need to fire off that message when appropriate

```
public AddCategory(Category newCategoryToAdd)
{
    Categories.Add(newCategoryToAdd);
    Messenger.Default.Send<CategoryAddedMessage>(new CategoryAddedMessage {AddedCategory = newCategoryToAdd});
}
```

..and then in your `FilterWindowViewModel`, we need to register to receive this message and keep it's collection in sync:

```
public FilterWindowViewModel()
{
    Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

    CategoryView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Categories);
    CategoryView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Type", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

    Messenger.Default.Register<CategoryAddedMessage>(this, m => ReceiveCategoryAddedMessage(m));
}
```

and then your receiving method would be:

```
private void ReceiveCategoryAddedMessage(CategoryAddedMessage message)
{
    Categories.Add(message.AddedCategory);
}
```

There are other techniques that can be used with MVVM Light, but hopefully this is enough to get you started and consider some approaches that may work for you.